# How to write specified columns and rows to excel file from an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Reposting this since no answer.

How can I write  multiple columns upto a certain row into an excel file from an exisiting data frame ?
The image below is the contents of my data frame say df2:

[image]

What I want to do is when I write the data frame to an excel, I want only the **first five values** of both the columns. I am able to fetch it for value.1 column with the following code:

`result2[header3] = (df2["Value.1"]).to_numpy()[0:6]`

I am unable to do the same for Parameter.1 columns similarly:
`result2 = (df2["Parameter.1"]).to_numpy()[0:6]`

Then the error given is :
 `` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices ``
The error is for the "Value.1" line.

Thank you in advance

P.S: using pandas

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly what you need, basically to only save the first 5 rows of your data to excel, you can do it with `head()`, and `to_excel`:

```
import pandas as pd
df.head(5).to_excel(r'C:\Users\....\filename.xlsx')
```